# Element looks overlapping/squeezing or do not have enough space (margin/padding)

Tags: discussion, support

I am wondering about an element that looks slightly overlapping or do not have enough space between reputation and top % and looks negative margin for me. While closely look the reputation element (.) inside it. Not an offense; I am bad at testing/analyzing elements.

Is it a bug/negative margin/need extra space?

[image]

Comment: In which browser?

Comment: There are many seemingly incomprehensible parts in your question. Can you fix it? Are you using Google Translate? E.g, what do you mean by *"looks negative margin for me"* and *"While closely look the reputation element (.) inside it."*?

Comment: What do you mean by *"negative margin"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen He means that it looks like the element has been moved up from the position where it would naturally have been placed by specifying a negative `margin-top` value in CSS. (There is no such negative margin on this element, by the way.)

Comment: The positioning is seemingly the same on the main site profile page, the difference is the background color of the reputation.

Comment: It happens on the meta sites for Electrical Engineering, Super User, Home Improvement, and I suspect for all the other sites, too.

Comment: The layout of that whole area looks crappy without the reputation graph that's shown on the main site.